# ruby - How to decrypt MD5 digested 5 digit PIN in ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, permutation, md5

So let's say I have a md5 hash of a five digits long PIN. It is given as string.

The only way is cracking it, means try every combination, hash it and compare it with the hash you want to crack. I'm trying to return the cracked PIN as string. Given the initial hash input is the md5 digest of the PIN (in a string). Here's my code:

```
require 'digest' 
def crack_PIN(hash)
  md5 = Digest::MD5.new
  permutations = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].permutation(5).to_a
  perm_digest = permutations.map{|element| md5.hexdigest(element.map{|num| "#{num}"}.join)}
  x = perm_digest.index(hash)
  permutations[x].map{|num| "#{num}"}.join
end
```

The problem with this code is that it only uses each number once (it can't repeat each number as many times as it wants). I'm trying to figure out what I can do to alter this code that would make it work for any amount of repetition of each number. Thanks :-)

Comment: Avoid converting enumerators to large arrays when it is not necessary to do so. You want something like `perm = ('0'..'9').to_a.repeated_permuation(5).find { |perm| ... }` (ref [Array#repeated_permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation)), though @Tom's suggestion is preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimal change:

```
permutations = '00000'..'99999'
```

That will get you the full list of all strings in the range. You can then just try running `md5.hexdigest` on each of them.

Also note: Your method is going to perform the *exact same* series of calculations every time you run it!! You would improve the performance by **caching** the calculated result somehow, (i.e. generating a lookup table of PIN --> md5 sum) and just referencing this in your code.

Comment: Otherwise known as a rainbow table.

Comment: ..."on each of them using [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)...

Answer (score 2):

Combining Tom and Cary's suggestions into a simplified version that needs less memory than your example because it does not store all hashes in memory. Furthermore, it returns the PIN as soon as it was found and does not generate all hashes upfront.

```
require 'digest' 

def crack_PIN(hash)
  md5 = Digest::MD5.new

  ('00000'..'99999').find { |pin| md5.hexdigest(pin) == hash }
end

crack_PIN("c4ded2b85cc5be82fa1d2464eba9a7d3")
#=> "45678"
```

Comment: Yeah, that's almost exactly what I ended up using.